# Speed of Nova or alternative launchers?

Tags: launcher

I'm thinking of getting the GS4, but plan to use Nova Launcher. When using an alternate launcher, will this negate any slowness or lagging introduced by TouchWiz?  Or is the damage done deeper in the ROM?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, and Nova is surprisingly snappy on it. You can change how fast the animations / transitions are. In my case, I set it to `faster than light`. If you're not content with that, you can go further and disable animations / delays via the phone's `Developer options` settings.

[image]